# "I should not have" for expressing you regret doing something in the past

Tags: past-tense, should

Usecase: I went out and got drunk yesterday. Now I regret the fact of drinking a lot yesterday.

> I should not have drunk a lot yesterday.

Is that correct?

In general: How can I say that I shouldn't do something in the past?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I should not have cheated on my income tax.  I should not have robbed the bank.  I should not have eaten those raw oysters.  Perfectly fine.

Comment: Your second sentence could be a little more succinct:  _Now I regret the fact of drinking a lot yesterday._ by omitting _the fact of'_. It would then read: _Now I regret drinking a lot yesterday_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've written is perfectly fine. Another common way to express it is to say

> I wish I hadn't drunk so much yesterday.

And if the acitivity you regret caused some other problems, it would be appropriate to apologize for that at the same time.

> I'm sorry I ___ed, I shouldn't have drunk so much.

But now we're getting more into interpersonal issues than language.